# coldfusion findNoCase not working

Tags: coldfusion

Anyone have any idea why this won't give me back anything?

```
findNoCase("flashvars.ID = ''",result.FileContent)
```

I know that `flashvars.ID = ''` is in the result, as I dump it out and can see it. When I do just...

```
findNoCase("flashvars.ID",result.FileContent)
```

It finds it! I could probably do a bunch of crap with `len()` `mid()` etc. to find out if the value of flashvars.`ID` is empty, but I just want to know why the first `findNoCase` doesn't work!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably a whitespace issue. Give this a shot:

```
#refindNoCase("flashvars\.ID\s*.=\s*.''",content)#
```

Comment: Sheesh...I tried a few RE's, guess I am not good at them...Thanks!

Comment: On a stylistic note, {0,} is more commonly written as *.  Both mean = or more.  + can be used for 1 or more.

Comment: I wonder if preserveSingleQuotes() would also help here...  Can't test at the moment, but I suspect that might be the issue (the single quotes are being escaped).

Comment: Then again, Marc's probably right and it's most likely a whitespace issue.

Comment: "I wonder if preserveSingleQuotes() would also help..." - Isn't that a special function only valid in cfquery tags?